# Cannot read property 'locales' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, locale, jquery-select2

I have that

> Cannot read property 'locales' of undefined

error when using select2-rails.

It raises somewhere here

> fn.select2.locales.ru

My application.js.coffee is

> #= require select2 
>     #= require select2_locale_ru

What could be a problem?

Comment: Your application js - are you sure it is not coffee? it should be `//=` rather than `#=`

Comment: yeah, sorry, it's application.js.coffee

Answer (score 0):

Move your script tags to `head` tag.

It will be solved.

but, I want other solution.

Check this link,

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1582